# The difference between getting a average number of times to get HH with one coin and with two coins

Tags: probability

Let the P(Head) = p such that p>0 for a bias coin.

It can be easily shown that average number of tosses needed to see a head is (1/p). I have derived that the average number of tosses needed to see a HH with 1 coin is (1+p)/p^2.

However, the average number of tosses needed to see a HH with 2 bias coins is 1/p^2.

It would be great if someone could answer my queries:

1.How do we arrive to 1/p^2

2. Why is there a difference between the 2 solutions? And what's the
   intuition behind it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The probability that $H$ appear for both coins is $p^2$, so it is equivalent to flip a single coin with probability of $H$ being $p^2$, and the expected value is $1\over p^2$.

(2) Getting two heads in a row is different from getting two at one time.

Basically, when you flip in a row, you can have $HH$, $THH$, $TTHH$, $TTTHH$,...

But when you flip two at the same time, you can only have $HH$, $**HH$, $****HH$,...

The key difference is that there is no case corresponding to $THH$ in the second case.